# Place absolute element always under other element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to design a notification icon (bell). When i click on it, i want to fadein a absolute div container with jquery (absolute element).
My problem is, that the div changes his location, if the window changes his size.

How can I "fix" my absolute element to prevent this?

Info: The absolute element is the notification - box.

CSS:

```
#notifi-content{
    margin: 1rem 0 0 0;
    height: 10rem;
    width: 10rem;
    background: #fff;
    border: 0.1rem solid #eee;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20%;
    left: 70%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="search-button">
        <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="notifi-content"></div>
```

EDIT

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SebiPuck/ngp20226/ 
Again: what I want: the notifi-content should be below my search-button, even if i resize the window.

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information. What does the HTML structure look like? And what is the desired output?

Comment: i updated it, i hope you can understand my problem now :)

Comment: "the div changes his location, if the window gets minor" - could you rephrase that? Fewer pronouns, and maybe describe what you mean by "minor", since that's not a past-tense verb.

Comment: hey, sorry for that. information: when i change the size of my window (browser), the absolute element moves faster then my icon(bell)

Comment: @Clank The key is the parent element of `notifi-content` div which has a relative position, you should post more code, looks like you will need some jquery to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

if you use percentages to fix the position of an absolute element what you describe (changes position when resizes) is a normal behaviour,

so you should use relative position and/or check if you can nest inside a wrapper to keep structure.

BTW If you put up a fiddle you'll get a lot more help easy_

---

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/ngp20226/1/) with **no** positioning property on div `#notifi-content` , just nested it in list;

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SebiPuck/ngp20226/ What I want: the notifi-content should be below my search-button, even if i resize the window.

Comment: i tried your version, works great, but i have to add "margin: 0 0 0 28.2rem;",because i have more list items. is there a better solution ?

Comment: add your list items to fiddle

Comment: here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/SebiPuck/ngp20226/2/ BTW: position: absolute; is necessary

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/maio/ngp20226/3/ - if it's ok please consider accepting answer

Comment: no, its not, it should be a horizontal navigation, otherwise my problem wont exist ^^

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using pixels instead of percent for the absolute positionning ?